# Download and run commands from server with .bat?

Tags: batch-file

I have a Windows 2008 server (A), I have a bat file (B) running on that server with a loop interval of one minute. Can I modify that bat file to download new instructions from server C, for example for moving folders and doing port forwarding (using netsh)?

Comment: We are going to need a little more information on what your trying to accomplish first.
Like what type of server like windows, asp, or apache.
Also exactly what your trying to download, run, ect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably do something hairy like this:

assume: c:\batch\b.cmd 
assume: c:\batch\extensions

copy new 'instructions' (aka cmd files) to c:\batch\extensions

in your b.cmd add:

```
@rem run extensions
for %%f in (c:\batch\extensions\*.cmd) do call :extension %%f

goto :EOF
:extension
call %1
REM Maybe remove the extension if it has run? check errorlevel?
goto :EOF
```